# Is it possible to list wi-fi or detect network controller through wine?

Tags: networking, wireless, windows, wine, hardware

guys!

I've googled about this with many different words and didn't find anything about it, except the information that it is not possible to install drivers on Wine, because it would not work.

Well, I'm trying to use the software "EasyMP Network Projection v2.86" to connect to an EPSON Wi-Fi projector (there's no client for Linux).
The software installation proceeds successfully in Wine, but on the step where the program scans for networks, it says that it can't find the network adapter and then it doesn't let me to proceed.

So I'm looking for a way to detect a network adapter (not to display hardware information, but to access the list of networks as it happens when you click on the OS wireless network icon. This list could have just the network which I'm connected to), or to browse the LAN through Wine.

I think it's not necessarily required the hardware information once it will need just to listen to Wi-Fi beacons or to access the SSID of the connected network.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: I don't know where my "hello" went to! I wrote "Hello, guys!"

Comment: No, you can't do it. Wine doesn't have direct access to hardware, so it can't "listen beacons".

Comment: Thank you! What about a way to browse a LAN?